# How do I get a cell's position within a range?

Tags: vba, excel

How would I go about getting the relative position of a cell within a range? Finding the position of a cell in a worksheet is trivial, using the `Row`- and `Column`-properties, but I am unsure of how to do the same within a range.

I considered using the position of the top-left cell in the range I want to find the position of a cell in, and just deduct it (-1) from the position of the cell in the worksheet, but it gets a little bit cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way to go about this?

My best attempt, including a test, so far is this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
  Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B2:E10")
  Dim c As Range: Set c = Sheet1.Range("C2")

  Debug.Print "Column in sheet: " & c.Column
  Debug.Print "Row in sheet: " & c.Row
  Debug.Print "Column in range: " & column_in_range(r, c)
  Debug.Print "Row in range: " & row_in_range(r, c)
End Sub

Function column_in_range(r As Range, c As Range) As Long
  column_in_range = c.Column - (r.Cells(1, 1).Column - 1)
End Function

Function row_in_range(r As Range, c As Range) As Long
  row_in_range = c.Row - (r.Cells(1, 1).Row - 1)
End Function
```

This gives the desired output:

```
Column in sheet: 3
Row in sheet: 2
Column in range: 2
Row in range: 1
```

But I wonder if there are any native functions I can use instead?

Comment: It looks like you are asking a CodeReview, think of us next time.

Comment: Don't forget, not all Ranges are contiguous rectangles. Whatever code you write should take this into account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*updated using variant provided by* `lori_m`

> But I wonder if there are any native functions ...

use this

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With Sheet1
        Set r = .[B2:E10]
        Set c = .[C2]
    End With
    If Not Intersect(r, c) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Column in sheet: " & c.Column
        Debug.Print "Row in sheet: " & c.Row
        Debug.Print "Column in range: " & Range(r(1), c).Columns.Count
        Debug.Print "Row in range: " & Range(r(1), c).Rows.Count
    End If
End Sub
```

output

```
Column in sheet: 3
Row in sheet: 2
Column in range: 2
Row in range: 1
```

Comment: I think this variation would be ok: `Range(r(1),c).Columns.Count` and `Range(r(1),c).Rows.Count`

Comment: wow, yes, you are also right, I've tested only with OP range) if you don't mind I will post your variant for the next users, or you can answer and I will vote up, and my answer will be deleted

Comment: No worries for post to be updated with above variant - the idea for it followed on from your initial suggestion in any case

Answer (score 5):

There is no native way to do it. I also do what you have mentioned in the code above. However I put some extra checks.

```
Sub test1()
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B2:E10")
    Dim c As Range: Set c = Sheet2.Range("C2") '<~~ Changed Sheet1 to sheet2
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Intersect(c, r)
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Check if the range is in main range
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    Else
        MsgBox c.Address & " in " & c.Parent.Name & _
               " is not a part of " & _
               r.Address & " in " & r.Parent.Name
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How certain are you that there's no native way to do it? If it's a certain thing I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: I am very certain but have been proven wrong couple of times in the past 3 years... I am a human after all :D

Comment: Hehe, I'll leave it open for a while longer then, and see if any other answers pop up.

Comment: Yup even I recommend that ;)

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion there is almost native way to check it but result is a string required some additional manipulation. All you need to use is a proper construction of `.Address property` (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff837625.aspx)). Some examples:

```
Dim r As Range: Set r = Sheet1.Range("B2:E10")

Dim c As Range: Set c = Sheet1.Range("c2")
Debug.Print c.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, , r.Cells(0, 0))
        '>>result: R[1]C[2]
'-----------------------------------------------------

Set c = Sheet1.Range("e2")
Debug.Print c.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, , r.Cells(0, 0))
        '>>result: R[1]C[4]
'-----------------------------------------------------

Set c = Sheet1.Range("e5")
Debug.Print c.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, , r.Cells(0, 0))
        '>>result: R[4]C[4]
'-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This seems quite similar to R3uK's solution, and while I suppose it is a native way of getting a string containing the values I want, I would much prefer not having to deal with extracting them from the string.

Comment: @eirikdaude, indeed, property is the same but the construction is totally different as R2uK's didn't recognized importance of first two parameters which have to be set to `False`. So, he is providing different solution compared to mine...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look [on MSDN to see more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff837625.aspx).

You can use something like :

```
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=True, _
                          ColumnAbsolute:=True, _
                          ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1, _
                          External:=False, _
                          RelativeTo:=Range("B2"))

'Or shorter version :
MsgBox ActiveCell.Address(, , xlR1C1, False, Range("B2"))
```

But you'll have both information about row and column in the range, but not separately.

So you'll still need to extract these values from the answer (look like : `R18C20`) in two functions, so almost the same issue...

Comment: I think I prefer my / Siddharth's way of doing it, but thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem, it is a classical issue and I was just pointing out another way to approach it as there is none native.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you are after.
But here it goes:

```
Sub ts2()

    Dim test As Range
    Set test = Range("B2:E10")

    Dim topcorner As Range
    Dim testcell As Range

    Set topcorner = Cells(test.Row, test.Column)
    Set testcell = Range("D7")
    rel_row = testcell.Row - topcorner.Row
    rel_col = testcell.Column - topcorner.Column

End Sub
```

By this, you will find the relative position.
But maybe you were looking for some built in function ?
If this was not the thing you were after, please edit your post...

Comment: **"But I wonder if there are any native functions I can use instead"** So, yes he is looking for a built-in function and you just did almost the same thing that he already posted, but far less properly.